# Making text appear in html table cell with line breaks

Tags: html, multiline, tabular

I'm working on a razor pages website with a database behind it. One of the database columns needs to contain multiline text. The text is entered by the user when creating a database entry so could be editted to include 
 tags or such like. When displayed on the webpage, this multiline data appears in a table cell like so:

```
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SpecSelResult.Output)
</dd>
```

However, line breaks do not show up. If I enter the text as 'Line1
 Line2
 Line3', when inspecting the element in chrome I see the following:

```
<dd>
    ::before
    "
       Line1<br> Line2<br> Line3
    "
    ::after
</dd>
```

And this displays as

```
Line1<br> Line2<br> Line3
```

so the 
 tags are ineffective.
Ideally I'd just be able to copy and paste the text from notepad or notepad++ and not add 
 tags, but adding the tags wouldn't be too bad if it worked.
Can anybody tell me how to get the data to show up multi-lined?

EDIT:

I've found this approach works if I add `<br>` tags but I'd still appreciate a solution without those:

```
<dd>
   @Html.Raw(Model.SpecSelResult.Output)
</dd>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved the problem for me:

```
<pre>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.SpecSelResult.Output)</pre>
```